# Accessing variable outside a function in React JS Frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I have written this code to access my `variable` outside the `function`.The value of `res`
outside the `function` is `undefined`. the outside console.log should print the `url` which is assigned to `res` inside the `function`. I will use this response in my `anchor` `tag` to open the `url` in `res` variable. What am I doing wrong?

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseconfig)
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp)
var res;
  const downloadurl = function() { getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'files/linpeas.txt'))
    .then((url) => {
       res = url
       console.log(res)
    })};
      
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Do you call `downloadurl()`?

Comment: Yes I am calling it in `Button`

Comment: I do not see nothing wrong with the code. The `console.log()` outside de function should return `undefined` but the one inside the function should return the info. Try adding a `.catch()` to show if there is some error

Comment: the outside `console.log` is printing `undefined` whereas it should print the `url` the is assigned to `res` inside the function

Comment: Can you please provide more information?
I think the function getDownloadURL is async so that the value (url) will be assigned to res when the function is executed or completed but the console log will run before executing the function.

Comment: I also tried without async function but the result is same the outside console is printing undefined.

Comment: Can you please provide me detail of getDownloadURL function so that we can together figure out the issue?

Comment: `getDownloadURL` is not written by me it is firebase storage method. My aim is to store this url in a variable and then I want to use this variable in anchor tag so that I can fetch the file in that url.

Comment: it is a promise so it would reach the `console.log` outside before setting the res to the url

Comment: @KeyvanKh what is the solution of this issue

Comment: where do you call the `downloadurl` ?? in a `useEffect`??

Comment: I am calling `downloadurl` in `button` `onClinck`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `useState()` to store `res` and the `useEffect()` to update `res` when this changes;

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseconfig)
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp)
const [res, setRes] = useState();

const downloadurl = () => { getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'files/linpeas.txt'))
    .then((url) => {
       setRes(url);
       console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
      
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(res);
  }, [res]);
```

Comment: not working again same undefined

Comment: I am not using useEffect as I am using this url in anchor tag to move to the url

Comment: If you can put more code or give more details would be useful

Comment: I have updated the question